# Create a Measure in Power Pivot / DAX that calculates available equipment based on date ranges

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerpivot, measure

I am looking for unit counts when the equipment is not in the date range (start and end dates).

How do I make a measure "AvailUnitCount" to give me unit counts by category in the timeline dimension (say November 11, 2018)?

I think it can be achieved via a measure in Power Pivot and date table, but I am just quite new to DAX and time dimension concept overall.

My measure reads:

```
AvailUnitCount := CALCULATE( DISTINCTCOUNT( EquipUsage[EquipmentNo] ) )
```

How do I incorporate time dimension into the measure above, so  I can report on available equipment for a specific date by moving a timeline in Excel?

Please see the data set and the desired outcome below. I immensely appreciate your advice on this.

**Table 1: EquipUsage**

```
EquipNo     CategoryNo  UsageStartDate  UsageEndDate
----------------------------------------------------
10005164    A020004004  5-Nov-18        5-Dec-18
10005167    A020004004  24-Oct-18       10-Nov-18
10005176    A020004005  9-Oct-18        5-Dec-18
10015982    A020004006  18-Feb-18       5-Sep-18
10019170    A020004006  16-Aug-18       30-Mar-19
10019551    A020004006  2-May-17        10-Nov-18
10005178    A020004007  20-Sep-18       15-Jan-19
```

**Table 2: EquipCategories** (Example of Desired Outcome for November 11, 2018)

```
CategoryNo  AllUnits    AvailableUnits
--------------------------------------
A020004004  2           1
A020004005  1           0
A020004006  3           2
A020004007  1           0
```

Comment: Why is `10005178` of category `A020004007` available on that date?

Comment: @AlexisOlson good job on spotting this discrepancy. I have corrected it to 0.

Answer (score 0):

The `AllUnits` measure is simple:

```
AllUnits = COUNTROWS(EquipUsage)
```

For availability, read in your desired date and sum up the rows where that date does not fall in the given date range:

```
AvailableUnits = 
VAR CheckDate = SELECTEDVALUE(DateTable[Date])
RETURN SUMX(EquipUsage,
           IF(
               EquipUsage[UsageStartDate] <= CheckDate &&
               EquipUsage[UsageEndDate]   >= CheckDate,
               0,
               1
           )
       )
```

Comment: thanks for response. However,  I am getting an error: Semantic Error: Failed to resolve name 'SELECTEDVALUE'. It is not a vaild table, variable, or function name. I am using Power Pivot with Excel Office 365 MSO (16.0.10827.20118) 32-bit. Here is the link to my data file: https://1drv.ms/x/s!AtU9m0XTdt8QoE6UDolT3mTX5J6q

Comment: That's a newer function that Excel and older versions of Power BI might not have. You should be able to replace it with `MAX`, but it's shorthand for `IF(HASONEVALUE(x), VALUES(x))`.

Comment: thanks but I haven't written much in DAX and I'm having really hard time putting this together and I am hoping that you could suggest the syntax for this scenario.

Comment: I suggested using `MAX` instead of `SELECTEDVALUE`.